# C# check MaskedTestBox empty

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

How can I check if a masked text box in C# is empty, i.e. the user has not entered anything?

My text box only allows 4 numbers to be input.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if `Text` property of the MaskedTextBox is `null` or `String.Empty`

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedTextBox1.Text))
{
    //no input
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked Liked a Charm.

Comment: If used in situations in which there are literals in the mask (such as a ZIP or SSN) this will not return the correct result unless `maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat == MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
maskedTextBoxInput.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
if (maskedTextBoxInput.Text == "")
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I found this to be the better solution. Otherwise if you're just using `MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals` (the default) and your mask is something like a ZIP code, you'll get back a misleading length (ex. the `Text` property is `"     -"`).